# Is any real closed extension of $\mathbb R$ characterized up to isomorphism by its ladder?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, fields

Let $R$ be a real closed field. Recall that the *ladder* of $R$ is the divisible, ordered abelian group obtained by quotienting $R$ by a certain equivalence relation.

Note that $R$ has trivial ladder iff $R$ is a subfield of $\mathbb R$. If $R$ has trivial ladder and $L$ is a divisible ordered abelian group, let $R\langle\!\langle x^L\rangle \!\rangle$ be the field of Puiseux series. Then $R\langle \!\langle x^L\rangle \!\rangle$ has ladder $L$. Conversely, from any real closed field, we may extract a maximal subfield of $\mathbb R$ and a ladder. I'm wondering whether that's all there is to it, i.e., whether every real closed field is of the form $R\langle\! \langle x^L \rangle\! \rangle$. Let me state this more formally:

**Questions:** Let $R$ be a real closed field with ladder $L$, and let $R_0 \subseteq R$ be a maximal subfield with trivial ladder.

1. Is $R$ characterized up to isomorphism by $R_0$ and $L$?
2. Is $R$ characterized up to isomorphism over $R_0$ by $L$?
3. The relative version: for any extension $R \to S$ of real closed fields such that $R_0 = S_0$, is $S$ characterized up to isomorphism over $R$ by the induced map on ladders?

As indicated in the title question, I'm happy to assume that $R_0 = \mathbb R$ if that simplifies things.

EDIT:  The first two paragraphs of this question were edited from the version to which @EmilJeřábek [responded](https://mathoverflow.net/a/308058).  In order that that answer can still make sense, the original first two paragraphs appear below.

> Let $R$ be a real closed field. Recall that $x,y \in R$ are *comparable* if there are $m,n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $mx > y$ and $ny > z$. Recall that the *ladder* of $R$ is the linear order obtained by quotienting by comparability.
>
> Note that $R$ has trivial ladder iff $R$ is a subfield of $\mathbb R$. If $R$ has trivial ladder and $L$ is a linear order, let $R^L$ be the real closure of the purely transcendental extension $R(L)$ with transcendence basis $L$, ordered as in $L$. Then $R^L$ has ladder $L$. Conversely, from any real closed field, we may extract a maximal subfield of $\mathbb R$ and a ladder. I'm wondering whether that's all there is to it, i.e. whether every real closed field is of the form $R^L$.

Comment: @LSpice feel free to clean it up any way you like. I was trying to allow Emil Jerabek's answer still make sense, but I think I failed to do that anyway.

Comment: @TimCampion A possibly related fact is the theorem of Erdös that if $R$ and $S$ are real closed fields of the same cardinality, such that the underlying orders $(R,\leq)$ and $(S,\leq)$ are saturated, then $R\cong S$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the initial claims in the question are false: the ladder of $R^L$ is *not* $L$. For example, for any $x\in L$, the field $R^L$ contains the element $\sqrt x$, which is not “comparable” to any element of $L$.

Not every linear order is isomorphic to a ladder of a real-closed field; for example, any such ladder is a dense order. In fact, a linear order is isomorphic to a ladder of a real-closed field if and only if it can be expanded to a divisible ordered group. This follows from the fact that any ordered field $(F,\le)$ carries a canonical structure of a valued field, with valuation ring $\{x\in F:\exists n\in\mathbb N\,(-n<x<n)\}$. Then the ladder of $F$ is exactly the underlying order of the value group of $F$. If $F$ is real-closed, its value group is divisible. Conversely, if $L$ is a divisible ordered group, the field of Puiseux series $\mathbb R\langle\!
\langle x^L\rangle\!\rangle$ is a real-closed field with value group $L$.

Now, the answer to all the questions is *no, not at all*. For instance, if $K$ is a dense subfield of $L$, then $K$ and $L$ have the same ladder; in particular, any real-closed field has the same ladder (in fact, the same value group and the same residue field) as its completion.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections and the answer. Let me see if I understand correctly: the field of Puiseux series $\mathbb R\langle \! \langle x^L \rangle \! \rangle$ is _not_ complete if $L$ is nontrivial, hence $\mathbb R\langle \! \langle x^L \rangle \! \rangle$ and its completion give an example of two nonisomorphic real-closed $\mathbb R$-algebras with the same ladder. Right? And is this the only obstruction -- are complete real-closed $\mathbb R$-algebras characterized up to isomorphism by their ladders?

Comment: Yes, Puiseux series give examples of incomplete real-closed fields. (If you want an explicit description of a complete, thus nonisomorphic, field with the same ladder, you may take the corresponding field of Hahn series.) Complete fields are still not characterized up to isomorphism, in particular, there are complete fields with proper extension with the same value group and residue field. *Maximally complete* fields have no such extensions (by definition); IIRC, these are just the Hahn series over $\mathbb R$.